# Exit jshell in java9 version

Tags: java-9, jshell

I recently upgraded to java9 and I am using the Jshell option which java provides.
I find it intuitive but I am not able to close the Jshell window, can someone suggest some command for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply type `/exit` to exit the jshell console.

you can find more info about jshell here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00

Answer (score 3):

Use `/exit` to exit the jshell.

For all the available options use `/help`.